# How to get the exact string from the list of string?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently developing an app using OCR(Optical Character Recognition) and I encounter this problem which is how to get the first name, last name and middle name from the line of text of full name. I try to use split to get the string into list of string.

```
var textline = 'Lastname Firstname Firstname Firstname Middlename'
List<String> splitted = ['Lastname', 'Firstname', 'Firstname', 'Firstname', 'Middlename']
var lastName = splitted.first;
var middleName = splitted.last;
```

Is there an easy way to get this right?

Comment: `List<String> splitted = ['Verganio', 'Kumar', 'van', 'Firstname', 'Ken']` From this list, can you know for certain which is a first name or which is a last name?

Comment: Unless there is a logical way to differenciate between a first name and last name, you cannot implement that in your code. However 1 way coulde  be, while doing the OCR, if you can prefix the firstname, lastname with special sysmbols then later you can use them  to identify and find from the list

Comment: First names, middle names, or last names could have spaces.  If you just want some arbitrary heuristic and will allow the user to manually correct it later, and you're just asking how to split `'Lastname Firstname Firstname Firstname Middlename'` into `['Lastname', 'Firstname Firstname Firstname', 'Middlename']`, you could use `String.indexOf(' ')` and `String.lastIndexOf(' ')` to get the appropriate indices and then use `String.substring` to extract the parts you want.